# Matching and returning a regex between two values

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to get the values from a string using regex, the value is that of the text between `tt="` and `"&`

So, for example, `"tt="Value"&"` I would only want to get the word `"Value"` out of this.

So far I have this: `/tt=.*&/` which gives me `"tt=Value"&`, Then, to get the value I am thinking to split the match on `=` and remove the 2 characters from the end. I feel though,  that this would be an awful way to do this and would like to see if it could be done in the regex?

Comment: You could do this through capturing group `tt=([^&]*)&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track for matching the entire context inside of the string, but you want to use a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to match/capture the value between the quotes instead of splitting on `=` and having to remove the two quote chars.

```
var r = 'tt="Value"&'.match(/tt="([^"]*)"/)[1];
if (r)
    console.log(r); //=> "Value"
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I am after I think, though is that `+`, supposed to be a `*`? That's how I've got it working. Can I ask though, what does the [1] do at the end? I've not seen that before. Does it omit the last character?

Comment: `[1]` returns the match of the capturing group, i.e the result that gets matched inside of the parenthesis `( ... )` and yes `*` is fine because the match is being checked by using the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't really the answer you are looking for since it doesn't involve regex but it's the way I usually do it.

```
strvariable = strvariable.Remove(0,strvariable.IndexOf("=") + 2);
strvariable = strvariable.Remove(strvariable.IndexOf("\""), strvariable.Length - strvariable.IndexOf("\""));
```

this would give you the result you were looking for which is Value in this instance.